# Problem starting a PHP background process

Tags: php, process, background

I have recently created a script that needs to be run on background.. I use this code to run it...

```
function run_in_background($Command, $Priority = 0) {
   if($Priority)
       $PID = exec("nohup nice -n $Priority $Command 2> /dev/null & echo $!");
   else
       $PID = exec("nohup $Command 2> /dev/null & echo $!");
   return($PID);
}
```

and use it like this

```
run_in_background('curl http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.php',5);
```

Unfortunately, it is not running on background...

I have also used:

```
shell_exec
```

instead of

```
exec
```

But it still doesn't work.. Is there something wrong with my setup?..

Note: it doesn't run in background but it sure runs when the page is loaded...

thanks in advanced..

Comment: please be very careful with this function, and clearly document how to use it properly.  if users can control the value of $Command or $Priority, then you have a command injection vulnerabiliity.  attackers will be able to execute commands on your web server os with the same permissions under which php runs.

Answer (score 0):

Place a `&` at the end of your command to tell the shell to run the process in the background.

```
$PID = exec("nohup nice -n $Priority $Command 2> /dev/null & echo $! &");
```

I also asked and answered a similar question you could look over that may help you: [How can I run a PHP script in the background after a form is submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626860/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-in-the-background-after-a-form-is-submitted)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer, seems to be exactly what you are looking for:

[php execute a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process/45966#45966)