# Saving pdf in the background using html2pdf

Tags: pdf, html2pdf

Am tryng to automatically generate pdfs using html2pdf class. I got the following code which is working fine, only that someone has to save the pdf manually. However, Whenever a new product is added, I would like to automatically save the pdf to some folder without user intervention, and store this value in a database for future reference.
How do I go about saving the pdf 'silently' i.e. in the background without showing any popups or requiring the user to intervene?
Thanks in advance.

```
 include('pdf_content.php');
 $content = ob_get_clean();
// convert to PDF
require_once('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
try
{
    $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
    $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
    $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
    $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
    //$html2pdf->Output($file_name.'_'.date("dmY").'.pdf');
    $html2pdf->Output($product_id.'_'.$file_name.'_'.date("dmY").'.pdf');
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try calling this script everytime a new product is added, although then you wouldn't really do it in the "background"...

For more information, please note the question ["How can I run a PHP script in the background after a form is submitted?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626860/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-in-the-background-after-a-form-is-submitted)

*EDIT:*

If you wish to save the file on the server instead of outputting it to the browser, you can use different parameters. [See also the html2pdf-wiki.](http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:output) Be aware that you cannot save the file on the user's computer unnoticed!

```
$html2pdf->Output('directory/file_xxxx.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: I noted the linked example but is it possible i run the script (not really in the background) without it showing popup to save the pdf? I want it to save the pdf without the user realising it. I dont have access to shell scripts and would prefer another option (preferably via php code) if that option exists. Rgds.

Comment: Thanks @Marty McVry. The option 'F' s what i was looking for. Rgds.

Comment: you saved me by writing this line "Be aware that you cannot save the file on the user's computer unnoticed!"  A big thanks buddy (^-^)