# Asynchronous php code in WP Plugin

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous, wordpress

Need to make this block of code asynchronous with the rest of the code. Its going to collect the wp posts and send a post request to my url. The plugin should run asynchronously and doesn't hamper the functioning of the wordpress site.

```
for ($x=0; $x<=n; $x++) {
$data = posts[$x];
$ch = curl_init('http://myurl.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'ACCEPT: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: If you want asynchronous, you'll probably have to go with Node.js or another alternative. PHP isn't friendly with asynchronous. [Basically the only alternative](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php).

Comment: Need to make this plugin for Wordpress itself and give it to bloggers so don't have an option other than PHP.

Comment: Again, PHP is *horrible* at this so anything you find will be a hacky workaround - but maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626860/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-in-the-background-after-a-form-is-submitted) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858883/run-php-task-asynchronously) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to process asynchronous requests in WordPress is to use WP-Cron to schedule an event. You can either schedule it to run once, or on an interval. See some guides on setting it up [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/16/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/). The two main functions to check out are [`wp_schedule_event()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) and [`wp_schedule_single_event()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event).

One thing to keep in mind however is that because your code is only running when there is a request, if there is low traffic then it's possible that your scheduled event won't run when expected. I wrote an article on my site regarding how you can use crontab in conjunction with WP-Cron to more accurately schedule events: http://justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress/disable-wp-cron-wordpress/.

Comment: From the post: `The way that I handle WP-Cron on my sites is to disable it entirely by setting the DISABLE_WP_CRON constant to false in wp-config.php.`...I think you've got it backwards there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Guzzle Package](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-guzzle-send-asynchronous-requests), code sample:

```
$request = $client->createRequest('GET', ['future' => true]);
$client->send($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'Got a response! ' . $response;
});
```

Look how can you [install it](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#installation). Also check the [RingPHP and Future Responses](http://mtdowling.com/blog/2014/09/28/guzzle-ring/) for some additional information. Actually [RingPHP](https://github.com/guzzle/ringphp) is utilized as the handler layer in `Guzzle` and at the bottom, the [React/Promise](https://github.com/reactphp/promise) is giving the `Promises/A` support for `PHP`.