# Write data to log file when PHP script finishes

Tags: php

It's a long running script and needs to be running even when user closed the browser.

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true); //run even when user disconnected.
set_time_limit(0); //run forever if that's what you need :)
$report = "";
while(1){
// do stuff and touch $report
}
//And the line below doesn't work when user disconnected.
file_put_contents("./offline.txt", $report, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

I have tried register_shutdown_function() but it doesn't seem to work. 
Is there any quick fix or other alternative solution which handles the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating another script and running it in the background?

[You can take a look at the 3rd answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626860/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-in-the-background-after-a-form-is-submitted)

Don't forget to put an ampersand (&) at the end of the command so that it will actually be run in the background, e.g.

```
exec('php newscript.php > /dev/null &');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use `crontab` to handle the script.
You don't specify how you must fire the script - if you run it in reply to user behavior - suggest to use `exec` but if you run it for example one a day - use `crontab`