# Keep PHP script running after PHP files is closed

Tags: php, html, multithreading

I have a webpage, which will be creating a buch of multithreaded calls before page contents are returned to the end user. The content of this php page are NOT dependent on the threads that it creates . The content of the page can (and most likely will) finish before the threads are finished

Here is a pseudo code

```
<?php

    // Step 1: Start php multithreading
    // CODE HERE (will probably take 20 seconds to finish)

    // Step 2: Do other stuff and return the php page, mostly static things using html
    // CODE HERE (will probably take 1 second to return)
?>
```

Now, if you look closely, the web page will still be "loading" until the code of step 1 above is finished (i.e., the page will show a rotating icon on the web browser until it is completely finished), which is about 20 seconds.

Moreover, if the webpage is closed, the script in step 1 is terminated halfway.

Now, I would like to do the following:

How to make the thread of step 1 independent of the page? i.e, if the page is closed, the thread keeps running.

Also, since the thread of step 1 is independent of the page, I want the page to finish loading once the content of step 2 are done, without waiting for step 1 to finish.

Thanks.

---

### Update

I am thinking this might be possible via a php script invoking another php script, but not sure how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run a PHP script in the background after a form is submitted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626860/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-in-the-background-after-a-form-is-submitted)

Comment: Maybe a queue could help. Then the webpage simply checks the status of the item in the queue.

Comment: can you please tell us what you want to achieve in step 1 ? so that we can suggest accordingly

Comment: try putting `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`
  `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300000000);` in ur php code and try what u r trying to do. it worked in my project

Comment: I think you can get your answer with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626860/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-in-the-background-after-a-form-is-submitted)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [fastcgi_finish_request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php). 
With this function you can return page content to user, but continue to execute your script on server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are approaching the right way. Probably with the long running and heavy task you should use a work queue to process them and send back to the user when it's finished. 
The work flow should be like this: Request -> create job and put them into queue -> check status of item in queue -> when it's done -> show response to the user. 
There are a lot of solution out there to achieve this architecture. 
Please take a look at this: http://queues.io