# Sending Bulk emails in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to send like 4000+ emails but individual emails to each using. Doing a foreach takes forever and the page loads until it finish (What really end up doing is an error).

I need to send those emails the best way possible and just leave the job in the background and return a response while that is happening.

If I didn't explain myself correctly, let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Have you looked into a Queue Job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626860/how-can-i-run-a-php-script-in-the-background-after-a-form-is-submitted

Comment: be super careful sending that much email, depending on on what email server and its set up this is  a great way to get black listed.

Comment: @nogad That answer is over 6 years old. `shell_exec` is completely unnecessary in this case. Queues are a *much* more elegant solution, and fall within the capabilities of the framework.

Comment: well it is how i still do it, but i dont use any framworks

Comment: @maiorano84 Thanks for the response.
But what about the foreach loop with 4000+ users? I think that mostly the issue.

Comment: ..... Queues run in the background on the command line. Seriously, did you read what I linked you to?

Comment: @maiorano84 is correct.  Use Queue Jobs.  They are amazing.

Comment: I highly recommend using a third party service to handle that much emails without handling it by yourself. That even guarantees accurate desirability too. Look for the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the best way to sending emails, I would highly suggest using a third party service.

There are many email services that guarantees sending your emails accurately to receivers inbox. Emails we send from our own email services provided by hosting providers mostly wind up in receivers spam folder. And also queuing up that much emails is not a solution as it would also bring up the question of what would happen if queue service failed.

I recently worked with a useful service which is named [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com). It helped me send that much emails without that much trouble.

You only need to loop though your data to format recipient and email content. Then send that data to sendgrid and they handle the emails.

refer [this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/using_the_smtp_api.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Gayan, I think you were the only one with a good explanation about my issue instead of just posting link of half my issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: @decastro4 glad you found it helpful