# How to continue processing PHP code after sending a http response

Tags: php, json, api, http, request

I wrote a PHP API where I receive data thru JSON that I write to a MYSQL DB.

I wish to send a HTTP 201 to the calling pgm before the INSERT to the db takes place. This is because sometimes I receive thousands of records and the time to process them is too long and the calling pgm times out.

I tried to place the http response instruction before the SQL INSERT code, but the HTTP response is not sent until the INSERT is completed.
Any recommendation is very welcome!

Comment: You're asking how to execute code in the background. Though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44305780/283366) might be an option for you

Comment: Thank you Phil. This brilliantly solved my problem!