# Set up a recurrent timer in PHP to run a script without cron

Tags: php, timer, cron, event-loop

In PHP, is there a way to set up a timer that would run a certain PHP script over and over again with some interval (e.g. 30 min)? I know it's sure possible with cron, but I'm more interested in a vanilla PHP solution.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143760/schedule-scripts-without-using-cron

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950304/run-a-php-cli-script-indefinitely

Comment: @BrianH. Well, not really that one